# Conditional statements with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascriptmvc

Sorry if this question seems stupid.
I'm making a kind of migration from javascriptmvc to angularjs. There is some point that is not exactly clear to me. Can I apply conditional statements on html with angularjs? Lets say I build the page depending on user login state. If user is logged in I hide login controls and show some welcome message. If user is not logged in then I show login controls. With javascriptmvc I can solve this with simply creating 2 different views and appending them according to data received - each view for each situation I described. It is easier because the controller is the entry point for the html building process and not the html.
Something like

```
<% if (data.logged_in){%>
 <div>
...some markup...
</div>
<%} else {%>
 <div>
...another markup...
</div>
<%}%>
```

How can I do such thing with angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version of Angular.js you can use this.

```
<div ng-if="{expression}">
   ..Some Markup ...
</div>
```

in previous versions (1.0.7)

```
<div ng-show="{expression}">
   ..Some Markup ...
</div>
```